# Unable to retrieve events/pictures for friend of a user through Facebook Graph API

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to build a WPF C# application which requires shared data of a friend of my application user. I have tried using this query https://graph.facebook.com/[User_Id]/?fields=photos. But it do not return the array of object as mentioned in the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/). Although the query https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=photos does return pictures for the user.

I am able to retrieve the friend's cover photo by `https://graph.facebook.com/[User_Id]/?fields=cover` but not the photos, albums, events e.t.c . I can see that they are listed under Connection. Could anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

To access friends data, you have to ask for the appropriate permissions. Cover photos are public that's why you were able to fetch it.

Friend's Photos and Albums : `friends_photos`
Friend's Events: `friends_events`

Graph API call to receive friend's photos:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/User_ID/photos?access_token=your_access_token
```

As you're developing in C#, you might be interested in the native [Facebook C# SDK](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html).

[EDIT]

Fetching Friend's Photos and events through C# SDK:

```
        var fb = new FacebookClient(Session["AccessToken"].ToString());

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        dynamic res = fb.Get("/User_ID?fields=photos,events");

        var photoID = res.photos.data[0].id;
```

Comment: Yes, I am also using Facebook C# SDK to login and get data from Facebook. My problem is that the Graph API call to retrieve a user's friend's connection (events, photos e.t.c) is not getting any data. Please check above.

Comment: I have asked for the friends_photos / friends_events permissions but still dont get the friend's data

Comment: @SambhavSacheti see the edited answer. That code works for me!

Comment: I have given these permissions - friends_photos,user_photos. fb.Get("/User_ID?fields=photos,events") only returns the UserID and no other data!.

Comment: it works for me perfectly, try debugging your code and check if it really has the permissions or not : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/